Find column that has the maximum value for each row
I have sample data as follows in my PieCloudDB Database:



ID
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5




1
100
150
120
130
110


2
200
250
220
330
320


3
400
350
320
330
430


4
400
450
520
430
400



I want to find the column that has the maximum value for each row.
Output:



ID
max_col




1
col2


2
col4


3
col5


4
col3



I tried this query and got the expected output
SELECT ID,
    CASE GREATEST(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
        WHEN col1 THEN 'col1'
        WHEN col2 THEN 'col2'
        WHEN col3 THEN 'col3'
        WHEN col4 THEN 'col4'
        WHEN col5 THEN 'col5'
    END AS max_col
FROM egData
ORDER BY id

But a problem I am encountering now is that when the number of columns increases(col6,col7,...), this method requires adding a large number of case when accordingly, which is too cumbersome. Is there a more concise way?

I think your current idea is the correct one to solve this task. If you have a lot of columns you want to select, you will usually need to write them. That's how SQL works, I wouldn't call that "cumbersome". Yes, there are options to fetch the list of columns from some information tables and maybe you can create a script that builds the query, but I doubt it would be less cumbersome.

Maybe you can consider using unnest to avoid a lot of WHEN THEN or UNION ALL.
SELECT ID, col_name AS max_col
FROM (
    SELECT ID, col_name,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY value DESC) AS rn
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, unnest(array['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']) AS col_name, -- add more cols
               unnest(array[col1, col2, col3, col4, col5]) AS value -- add more cols
        FROM your_table
    ) AS subquery
) AS result
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id;

